# Issues with updating my app version in gradle file

Tags: android, gradle, version

So I was using API 25 which is Nougat version, and I wanted to update my app to Version ApI27 which is newly out these days. but whenever I update to `27.0.1`, this Error:

```
"Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7.27.0.1"
```

keeps occurring. I don't know what I've done wrong and I'm struggling all day to find the resolution. Thank you very much for your time and assistance in this matter.

Oh, and I'm sure that I've downloaded SDK Versions and all the files that are needed already in SDK manager.

My Gradle File(Module App):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.1'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "org.poream.dejaview"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {


implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.6.0'
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
{
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7.27.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.6.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

My Gradle File(Project):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to 
all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {

    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    google()
}
dependencies {

    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך It is not a duplicate. There is the google maven repo. Check the answer below. There is a typo

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti: My bad mistake. I'll retract the flag. Thank you for the info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a **typo** (the `.` instead of `:`)

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7.27.0.1'
```

Use:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! I was dumb to make that mistake : )

Comment: @poream3387, Agreed!

Answer (score 1):

Add **maven { url 'https://maven.google.com/' }** line in your project level build.gradle

> 

```
   repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com/' }
    }
```

Comment: It is wrong. There is in the build.gradle the google maven repo google(). Check my answer below. There is a typo.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. but I'm afraid to tell you that it doesn't work :(

Comment: @poream3387 it doesn't work since this maven is just in your build.gradle with the shortcut google(). Check my answer below. You have a simple typo in your dependency